# props not passing to component react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

We have a component, notification cell, where if you click the notification cell, it opens up a screen with the post details. However, the notification cell is not passing the props to the post details screen.

Notification Cell:

```
showThoughtsPage = async() => {
  await firebase.firestore()
    .collection('thoughts')
    .doc(this.state.postID)
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        console.log(doc.data().username) //<--- works

        this.state.navigation.push('ThoughtsDetails',
        {
          Tusername: doc.data().username,
          Tdescription: doc.data().description,
          Timage: doc.data().image,
          Tdate_created: doc.data().date_created,
          TlikesCount: doc.data().likesCount,
          TcommentsCount: doc.data().commentsCount,
          TviewsCount: doc.data().viewsCount,
          Tcategory: doc.data().category,
          TpostID: doc.data().postID,
          Tuid: doc.data().uid,
          Tlink: doc.data().link,
          TmediaType: doc.data().mediaType,
        })
      }
    });
}
```

Post details screen:

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
   username: this.props.Tusername,
   image: this.props.Timage,
   description: this.props.Tdescription,
   postID: this.props.TpostID,
   link: this.props.Tlink,
   navigation: this.props.navigation,
   date_created: this.props.Tdate_created,
   viewsCount: this.props.TviewsCount,
   isLoading: true,
   currentUser: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
   posterUID: this.props.Tuid,
   mediaType: this.props.TmediaType,
   modalOpen: false,
   commentsArray: [],
   currentViewsCount: 0,
};
console.log(this.props.Tusername + " username") // <--- undefined
```

}

Any idea where we are making the mistake?

Comment: you need to use `this.setState` to update a state, you can't update it by overriding the property

Comment: @Sysix where specifically does that matter? I am initializing the state in the constructor in post details with this.state, and not using state in the notification cell

Comment: you are updating the state when the async request from `showThoughtsPage ` is finished, also states from the parent dont need to be reinitialize in a child component. when the prop is updating, the component will also do

Comment: @Sysix maybe im missing something. Where in showThoughtsPage am I updating the state? I pull the info from firebase and pass it directly to the thoughts page, the only time I access state is when I call navigation, are you saying that when I call navigation I need to setState? and can you provide an example as an answer of what you mean if this is the case, because I am not really following

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - I needed to access the props in post details like so:

```
  username: this.props.route.params.Tusername,
  image: this.props.route.params.Timage,
  description: this.props.route.params.Tdescription,
  postID: this.props.route.params.TpostID,
  link: this.props.route.params.Tlink,
  navigation: this.props.route.params.navigation,
  date_created: this.props.route.params.Tdate_created,
  viewsCount: this.props.route.params.TviewsCount,
  isLoading: true,
  currentUser: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
  posterUID: this.props.route.params.Tuid,
  mediaType: this.props.route.params.TmediaType,
  modalOpen: false,
  commentsArray: [],
  currentViewsCount: 0,
```